# Understanding lambda functions in python

Tags: python, function, lambda

I am new to python and I created a script to sort through "show ip accounting" information from a cisco router. The script reads a file and breaks up every line into a list, then it creates a list of every line. So I end up with a list of lists:

```
list a = [[192.168.0.1,172.16.0.1,3434,12222424],[192.168.2.1,172.12.0.1,33334,12667896722424]]
```

I want to be able to sort by the third column or 4th columns of the list within the list.

I was able to do it using a lambda function, but my question is how to duplicate this using a standard function?

here is my code below:

```
from sys import argv

script, option, filename = argv
a=[]
b=[]

def openfile(filename):
  file = open(filename)
  for line in file:
    if not line.startswith("  "):
      a.append((line.split()))
  return a

def sort(a,num):
  b = sorted(a, reverse=True, key=lambda x: int(x[num]))
  return b

def top5(b):
  print "Source     Destination Packets     Bytes"
  for i in b[:4]: 
    print i[0]+"    "+i[1]+"    "+i[2]+"        "+i[3]

def main(option):
  a = openfile(filename)
  if option == "--bytes":
    b = sort(a,3)
    top5(b)
  elif option == "--packets":
    b = sort(a,2)
    top5(b)
  else:
    print """
    Not a valid switch, 
    --bytes to sort by bytes 
    --packets to sort by packets."""


main(option)
```

So my question is how can I duplicate the lambda function as a standard custom sort function? I am trying to figure out how this works.

`b = sorted(a, reverse=True, key=lambda x: int(x[num]))`

Comment: Check out the [Python Sorting HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)'s section on "key functions".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I duplicate the lambda function as a standard custom sort function?

Do you mean this:

```
def sort(a, num):
  def key(x):
    return int(x[num])
  return sorted(a, reverse=True, key=key)
```

or perhaps this:

```
from functools import partial

def key(num, x):
  return int(x[num])

def sort(a, num):
  return sorted(a, reverse=True, key=partial(key, num))
```

?

Comment: I guess they're actually looking for itemgetter.

Comment: @thg435: Maybe. Hard to say really. "Standard custom function" is a bit of an oxymoron.

Comment: OK, so I tried both snippets of code and they both work, My question is when you made the function key inside of the function sort, what value does it get for x, if you don't send it any values when you call it with key=key? I am trying to understand how this works,

Comment: @user2010044: `x` refers to the list item whose key is being requested. `sorted()` calls `key()` for every element in the list, and then uses the keys it got to do the actual sorting.

Comment: So the sorted function handles the iteration of the list for me, so in essence sorted is saying for every item in list call key(current_index)?  Is that what is is doing?

Comment: @user2010044: `sorted()` calls `key(a[i])` for every index `i`, and then reorders the elements of `a` so that their keys appear in non-ascending order.

Comment: I think where I went wrong was my key function was a separate function and not inside the sort function. so it needs to be a function inside the calling function for it to work?

Comment: @user2010044: It needs to be a function that takes a single argument (the element). What makes it a little complicated is that it needs to access `num` (that's why I had to use `partial()` when declaring `key()` outside `sort()`).

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am starting to understand how this works, thanks.

Comment: @user2010044: A key function doesn't necessarily have to be defined inside the calling function. But it you want to create a closure over a local variable inside that function, _then_ you need to define it there (or use `functools.partial`, or wrap it in a local function or a `lambda`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Python provides [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for doing this kind of thing:

```
def sort(a, num):
    return sorted(a, reverse=True, key=operator.itemgetter(num))
```

Edit

As @NPE pointed out, that doesn't convert the key to an `int` for sorting. For that, you're best off to stick with a lambda.

Comment: @NPE True. I missed the cast to int

Comment: You could do `compose(int, operator.itemgetter(num))`, if you had a `compose` function from somewhere (e.g., [`functional`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/functional)). But I don't think this is what the OP is asking for.